# What tools for documenting a big project you use?

Tags: php, documentation, project

I'm working at a project with a friend. This project became big, there are a lot of classes, methods, functions, helpers, etc..

I feel the need for something which will help us to read the others code. The project is built on a public framework(laravel), it is MVC.

Do you use a tool which helps you with this? The code is documented, but I think it's a little hard to read every file to find out how things works.

Thank you.

Comment: phpDocumentor? [http://www.phpdoc.org/](http://www.phpdoc.org/)

Comment: Thank you, it seems to be what I need. It will generate a documentation page like my framework does, or other technologies which I used, or even php.net.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[phpDoc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHPDoc) will help, you set up a comment before every function like this:

```
/**
 * Returns a user's e-mail address
 * 
 * @param int $userId
 * @return string
 */
```

Most major IDEs then read these, so you'll be able to see the return type as you call the function via code completion.